# Usage of TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy in log4j2 configuration

Tags: spring-boot, log4j2

I am trying to use TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy with log4j-2.13.2 which comes embedded with spring-boot 2.3.0.RELEASE (spring-boot-started-log4j2). 
The expected functionality is that a log file should be created for each day.

My configuration file looks like this:

```
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = fileAppender
appender.rolling.fileName = ${basePath}/log-${date:yyyyMMdd}.log
appender.rolling.filePattern = ${basePath}/log-${date:yyyyMMdd}-%i.log
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy
appender.rolling.policies.time.interval = 1
appender.rolling.policies.time.modulate = true
```

However, when starting the application, the following exception is thrown:

```
2020-05-28 23:39:07,991 main ERROR Could not create plugin of type class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender for element RollingFile: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pattern does not contain a date java.lang.IllegalStateException: Pattern does not contain a date
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.PatternProcessor.getNextTime(PatternProcessor.java:154)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy.initialize(TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy.java:117)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.CompositeTriggeringPolicy.initialize(CompositeTriggeringPolicy.java:54)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager.initialize(RollingFileManager.java:158)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:153)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender$Builder.build(RollingFileAppender.java:62)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.util.PluginBuilder.build(PluginBuilder.java:122)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createPluginObject(AbstractConfiguration.java:1002)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:942)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.createConfiguration(AbstractConfiguration.java:934)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.doConfigure(AbstractConfiguration.java:552)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.initialize(AbstractConfiguration.java:241)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AbstractConfiguration.start(AbstractConfiguration.java:288)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.setConfiguration(LoggerContext.java:618)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.start(LoggerContext.java:295)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:240)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator.initialize(Configurator.java:159)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator.initialize(Configurator.java:131)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator.initialize(Configurator.java:101)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator.initialize(Configurator.java:188)
```

If I change the file pattern:

```
appender.rolling.fileName = ${basePath}/log-%d{yyyyMMdd}.log
appender.rolling.filePattern = ${basePath}/log-%d{yyyyMMdd}-%i.log
```

the exception is not thrown anymore, but the name of the file is "log-%d{yyyyMMdd}.log" instead of "log-20200528.log" (for example).

How should I specify the filePattern property in order to achieve the expected behavior (generate a log file for each day, with the current date enclosed in the filename)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems a combination of the two approaches is needed in order to achieve the expected behavior:

```
appender.rolling.fileName = ${basePath}/log-${date:yyyyMMdd}.log
appender.rolling.filePattern = ${basePath}log-%d{yyyyMMdd}-%i.log
```